# The properties of almost all directed graphs

Tags: reference-request, graph-theory, random-graphs, directed-graphs

A mathematician on the forum previously [requested a reference on human brains modelled as directed graphs](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/255855/human-brains-considered-as-directed-graphs). This makes sense as neurons are mostly unidirectional and I have been thinking about similar things recently.

In the same vein, might there be a good reference on random directed graphs that includes a section on the properties of almost all directed graphs? I must add that I'm looking for a text that is self-contained.

**Addendum:**

To clarify what I mean by property it may be useful to provide a few examples in the case of simple graphs. Almost all simple graphs have diameter 2, are connected and are Hamiltonian [1].

### References:

1. Anuj Dawar and Erich Grädel. Properties of Almost All Graphs and Generalized Quantifiers. 2010.
2. Edward T. Bullmore and Danielle S. Bassett. Brain Graphs: Graphical Models of the Human Brain Connectome. 2011.
3. Danielle S. Bassett and Edward T. Bullmore. Small-World Brain Networks Revisited. 2017.

Comment: Just one result, so not an answer to your question: Almost every $r$-regular digraph is Hamiltonian for $r \ge 3$. Cooper, Colin, Alan Frieze, and Michael Molloy. "Hamilton cycles in random regular digraphs." *Combinatorics, Probability and Computing* 3, no. 1 (1994): 39-49.